# Porting to WinRT: Registry information in HKLM/.../TimeZoneInfromation for WinRT/WIN 8 mobile apps

Tags: windows-runtime, porting

I am trying to port a piece of code to WinRT. The code uses [GetTimeZoneInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to get time zone information. I validate this information further by querying the Registry. I use following registry keys for the same.

1)(HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\) 
2)(HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones).

I can explain more if required.

I am hoping WinRT kept this information in some other structure which can be accessed. Does anyone know of any API/Method, WinRT provides as an alternative way to access the information it used to store in the following keys?
Please let me know if i should add more.

Thanks

Comment: Which further information are you retrieving from the registry that is not available via API? `GetTimeZoneInformation` [can be used from WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br205762.aspx#time).

Comment: The StandardName and DaylightName members of the resultant TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION structure I get from `GetTimeZoneInformation`  are localized according to the current user default UI language.
 My application uses a different convention to mark locale names. Hence say Window tells me the locale name is "India Standard Time", I convert it to "Asia/Calcutta". This is do using a c++ map. The information in this map is non localized. I cannot create maps for all locales.
 The registry kept this information in non-localized form allowing use my Map. Now without registry this is problem.

Comment: You definitely can't access registry from Windows Store apps and I also didn't notice any APIs returning non-localized names while browsing through the reference. Couldn't you use bias (offset) info as the key for your mapping?

Comment: I suspect that bias info can be same for few locales.